# Determining Integral of $[f(x)]^4*[g(x)]^5$

Tags: calculus, integration

There are two functions

$$f(x)=\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{2} \:\:\text{and}\:\: g(x)=\frac{e^x- e^{-x}}{2}$$

We know that $f'(x)=g(x)$ and $g'(x)=f(x)$ and $[f(x)]^2−[g(x)]^2 = 1$.

We need to determine

$$\int [f(x)]^4[g(x)]^5 dx$$

I tried several times but I keep getting different answers. I could really use some help. Thank you!

Comment: Hint: $f(x)=\cosh(x)$ and $g(x)=\sinh(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

$\int f^4( g^4 \cdot g) dx$

$\int f^4 (g^4) (g)dx$

$\int f^4 (f^4-2f^2+1) (g) dx$ since we are given $g^2=f^2-1$

$\int (f^8-2f^6+f^4) (g) dx$

Let $u=f$ so then $du=f' dx$

We are given that $f'=g$ so $du=g dx$

Therefore we have the integral in terms of our substitution is

$\int (u^8-2u^6+u^4)  du$

Answer (score 0):

We define 
$$I_{m,n}=\int f(x)^mg(x)^ndx$$
Then we recall that 
$$(a+b)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}a^kb^{n-k}$$
Then we see that 
$$\begin{align}
f(x)^m&=\left(\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}2\right)^m\\
&=\frac1{2^m}\sum_{k=0}^m{m\choose k}e^{kx}e^{-(m-k)x}\\
&=\frac1{2^m}\sum_{k=0}^m{m\choose k}e^{(2k-m)x}
\end{align}$$
As well as $$g(x)^n=\frac1{2^n}\sum_{j=0}^n(-1)^{n-j}{n\choose j}e^{(2j-n)x}$$
Hence we have that 
$$f(x)^mg(x)^n=\frac1{2^{m+n}}\sum_{k=0}^m\sum_{j=0}^nR_{n,j}^{m,k}e^{(2j+2k-n-m)x}$$
Where $$R_{n,j}^{m,k}=(-1)^{n-j}{n\choose j}{m\choose k}$$
So we obtain
$$I_{m,n}=\int \frac1{2^{m+n}}\sum_{k=0}^m\sum_{j=0}^nR_{n,j}^{m,k}e^{(2j+2k-n-m)x}dx$$
Which is 
$$I_{m,n}=\frac1{2^{m+n}}\sum_{k=0}^m\sum_{j=0}^nR_{n,j}^{m,k}\int e^{(2j+2k-n-m)x}dx$$
Next we compute 
$$\int e^{ax}dx$$
setting $x=u/a\Rightarrow dx=du/a$ we have $$\int e^{ax}dx=\frac1a\int e^udu=\frac1ae^{ax}$$
So we get
$$I_{m,n}=\frac1{2^{m+n}}\sum_{k=0}^m\sum_{j=0}^nR_{n,j}^{m,k}\frac{e^{(2j+2k-n-m)x}}{2j+2k-n-m}$$
Note that this only works when one of $m,n$ is even and the other is odd. Your case is given by $I_{4,5}$.